# Help with CD title for Swedish historical society

Tags: possessives, titles, book-title

I would be very grateful for some help with this title for a CD.

"Andrew & Elsa Peterson – the genuine pioneer story"

The CD issuers from a historical society want to put the above as title.
I'm wondering if there should be a genitive construction? like: ...*the genuine pioneers' story*. Is there another better title considering that they have to add "*The real people behind the fictional characters from the famous Emigrant novels*" somewhere at the bottom of the CD? to explain why this story is the genuine one. Do you think they should add Swedish or Scandinavian, since Andrew & Elsa were from Sweden? should they write *"the people that the fictional characters were based on"* ...etc instead?

Comment: Is this a documentary CD or something like that, rather than a music CD with songs on it? Is the CD actually a story?

Answer (score 2):

*Genuine* sounds a bit odd here. When used to describe people, *genuine* normally relates to their **personality**, rather than their existence; so the implied opposite to *genuine* is not *fictitious/literary*, but rather *dishonest/deceitful*. “The genuine pioneer’s story” makes it sound like it’s the story of a pioneer with a very pure and honest disposition (rather than the story of a pioneer who was a liar and a cheat).

When applied to something like a story, *genuine* normally pertains to the objective and verified veracity of something; its opposite is something along the lines of *counterfeit*. “The genuine pioneer story” makes it sound like this is a verified, non-counterfeit story about pioneers, the implication being that there is another, unverified and false story somewhere as well.

More appropriate adjectives would be *real* or *true*. While both of these are also antonyms of *fake, false*, they are commonly used to separate real-world characters and stories from fictitious ones (and they certainly don’t say anything about a person’s personality or disposition). For example, when a movie is said to be “based on a true story”, that doesn’t imply that there is a false story going around also, just that the movie is based on events that took place in the real, non-fictitious world (even *the real world* uses *real* here). Indeed, [this Visit Östergötland page](http://www.visitostergotland.se/en/products/195814/Release-party-Andrew-and-Elsa-the-true-pioneer-story/) uses *true* in the title for a launching event of the *Andrew & Elsa* CD in July.

In addition, it sounds a bit unnecessary and not very ‘title idiomatic’ to have *story* as part of the title in English. This is quite language-dependent (and perhaps also purely subjective), but while in Swedish, the title *Andrew och Elsa – den äkta pionjärhistorien* sounds quite natural as the title of a “musical audio book” (as they call it), I think it would follow the general tendencies of titles in English better to simply call the English version *Andrew and Elsa: the true pioneers*.

The explanatory subtitle could then include the story bit: “The story of the people who inspired the characters in the renowned *Emigrant* novels” or something like that.

Comment: Thank you so much! Now we can start rethinking the title – and I hope you won't mind if we use your title? /Kind regards, Blom

Comment: Not at all. But do wait and see if someone else chimes in with differing viewpoints before settling on anything final.

Comment: If something is genuine, it means it is not a copy, or an imitation. And "true" can mean "genuine" as in *this is a true/genuine/real Rolex watch*. So... "True pioneers" *might* still be interpreted to mean pioneers who are the real McCoy, as in these two are not make-believe pioneers. "The true story of bla... and bla..." would help to disambiguate the title.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Yes, it might; but when describing people, _genuine_ most commonly means ‘heartfelt, undeceiving, honest’, while _true_ at least doesn't mean that as often. The meaning ‘real-life (as opposed to literary, fictitious)’ is also well-established in the phrase “Based on a true story”.

Comment: How can you recommend "real" and "true" if you want to avoid opposites of "fake" and "false"?  Those worsen the problem by being perfect antonyms.

Comment: @MatthewRead They don’t really _worsen_ the problem, because _genuine_ is also a perfect antonym. But unlike _genuine_ (which, when applied to people, most commonly describes their personality, and certainly is not commonly used to describe whether someone is a real-world person or not), _real_ and _true_ are both established in the desired use here, of specifying that someone belongs to the real world, rather than fiction. There is no ideal, completely unambiguous word here, but some are better than others, and _genuine_ is definitely worse than _true_ or _real_.

Comment: Thank you again for your replies! When I first talked to the CD issuers I pointed out that there was a problem with the words 'genuine' and 'story' in their title. The thorough explanation as to why this is  – that I got here, helped them to see my point, thanks... In their (musical) audio book they i.a. want to educate amateur historians about how famous Swedish author Moberg used the real life-couple Andrew&Elsa as templates for his fictitious characters Karl-Oskar&Kristina.

Comment: Moberg found Andrew's diaries in the library of St. Paul in 1948. Famous author Astrid Lindgren found and read Andrew's diaries first, but she lost two weeks traveling and was turned down by her publisher and instead Moberg got to write the book of the decade. It has been said that in the light of these events Moberg wanted downplay the likeness to the diaries. However the similarities are obvious. This is what the CD issuers want the CD title with accompanying text to describe.